# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting Cell in One Sheet based on Other Sheet Index Match Value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I am using Google Sheets 2019 Calendar template. There is a cover page that shows all of 2019 and individual pages where you can input specific daily details.

[image: Summary Google Sheet Calendar Page]

[image: November 2019 Page]

I was able to use this formula to determine whether or not the cell in March 2019 that matched W7 (3/1/2019) was blank or not. This formula functions.

```
=not(isblank(INDEX('Mar 19'!$B$4:$H$15,($Z7+($Z7-1))+1,MATCH(W7,$R7:$X7,0))))
```

The formula could be simplified slightly but this is how it makes the most sense in my head.

However, when I try to enter it into conditional formatting to get the cell to highlight, it says the formula is incorrect.

Any idea on how to get this to work so that the conditional formula functions and adjusts for each cell correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conditional formatting can't intake reference from another sheet. you need to **`INDIRECT`** it:

```
=NOT(ISBLANK(INDEX(INDIRECT("'Mar 19'!$B$4:$H$15"), ($Z7+($Z7-1))+1, MATCH(W7, $R7:$X7, 0))))
```